# Window Store app - return value to calling page

Tags: windows-8

I have a WinRT "Windows Store" app with two pages: a list page and an edit page. When the user clicks a list item and selects "Edit" from the bottom app bar, I pass the item to the edit page. What I need from there is to support two possible user actions:

- If the user navigates back using the Back Button (top navigation), I want the unmodified item to be returned the calling page.
- If the user clicks on a supplied "Save" button (on the edit page), I want to update the various properties of the item, save it to a data store and automatically return the modified item to the calling page.

Either way, the calling page needs to update its display with the changes made to the item, if any. I can do most of this, but I can't figure out how to return the item to the calling page. How do I go about this?

Please keep in mind, there will be other pages added to the app going forward (which will also be called from the main "lists" page). I need to make an accommodation such that when I return from a given "child" page back to the lists page, the behavior of the list page will differ based on which page is being returned from. (Hope that makes sense...).

Bonus question: I'd also like to capture the back navigation event to notify the user that the modified item will not be saved and give them the option to continue, save and continue or cancel the return navigation action. Is that possible?

TIA

Comment: are you using C#/XAML or HTML5/JS?

Answer (score 1):

I decided this approach was the wrong one to take for the problem I'm trying to solve. I never found a particularly good way to return a value from the child page back to the parent page.

Instead, my problem allowed a different approach. I have a master List<> of items I'm tracking within the application. This List<> is serialized to local storage. I pass in either an existing item (for an edit) or a null instance (for an add) when I call the child page.

When I get to the child page, I pull up the passed in item in the LoadState method. If the item passed in is null, I create a new instance which becomes my working instance.

From there, I allow the user to edit the item as desired. When the user saves the item, I deserialize the master List<> from storage. I then either add the new item to the master List<> or replace the existing item in the List<>. I then reserialize the master List<> to storage, replacing what ever was already there.

When the user returns to the calling (parent) page, I reacquire the master List<> of items from storage in the LoadState method and repopulate the page. If an existing item was updated or a new item was added, the parent page accurately reflects the change. That was ultimately all I needed to have happen.

I don't know if there is a way to do what I was originally asking but in this case at least I decided I don't need to do that. It may be that this alternate approach, or something similar, is the only way to pass objects to a parent page in the navigation stack on a "Back" event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if I'm understanding your question, that you are looking for something along these lines:

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/path/to/your/page.html", {/*this object will be the second 'options' parameter to your page's ready function });
```

. . .

```
// This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It populates the page elements with the app's data.
ready: function (element, options) {
```